# Maximo Anywhere Create Follow-Up Workorder issue

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am using Anywhere 7.5.2 (Work Execution), The create follow-up work orders are creating the work orders properly but I need to filter the work order with status as "INPRG - In Progress" only. How to do that ?

Comment: are you attempting to limit the workorder status change list to only In progress?

Comment: Yes. I dont want to see the waiting on material and other status in the MY ASSIGNED WORK